# How can I theme an image inside a field formatter

Tags: media, 8

I'm trying to change the output of an image field so that I can display it using a Javascript image gallery. I have the basic field formatter set up, but I'm having trouble finding the correct place to override the theme that displays the `<img>` tag itself.

I'm overriding the viewElements function of the core ImageFormatter:

```
class ImageGalleryFormatter extends ImageFormatter {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items) {
    $elements = parent::viewElements($items);
    foreach ($elements as &$element) {
      $element['#theme'] = 'imagegallery_format';
    }

    $elements['#attached']['library'][] = 'imagegallery_formatter/light-gallery';
    return $elements;
  }

}
```

There I can set my custom Twig theme for each element, but that theme only writes the stuff directly around the `<img>` tag, not the tag itself. The theme provides access to an `{{ image }}` variable that renders the actual image. I tried accessing the variables inside the image like `{{ image.uri }}`, but that didn't work. I know the information I need is in there as I dumped the image variable in Twig and can see the array, but I can't access it from here.

From the Twig debug output I know that `'core/themes/classy/templates/field/image.html.twig'` is the theme I need to override, but I can't find a way to do that from my module. I read the source of the core ImageFormatter viewElements function, but I don't see the image variable there and don't understand how I can modify it.

How can I override the theme that renders the `<img>` tag of an image field in my field formatter?

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!image.html.twig/8 here I can see tag . U need to create templates subfolder in module folder and put there appropriate twig file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no expert on field formatters in D8, but are you opposed to using a preprocessor? If not, have a look at [template_preprocess_image_formatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21image.field.inc/function/template_preprocess_image_formatter/8). It looks like that is where you would prepare your own variables for use in the image formatter template. Cheers -